# how do you test golang command line output

Tags: testing, go

I'd like to test the output of a golang command line app, but I'm not quite sure how to do that with go's testing library.

Let's say I have a program like this:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    const (
        cityDefault = "San Francisco"
        cityDoc     = "the city you want the forecast for"
    )
    var city string
    flag.StringVar(&city, "city", cityDefault, cityDoc)
    flag.StringVar(&city, "c", cityDefault, cityDoc)
    flag.Parse()

    fmt.Println(city)
}
```

I'd like to test that both of these:

```
$ ./myapp -c "Los Angeles"
$ ./myapp -city "Los Angeles"
```

... output `Lost Angeles`.  So, I guess the question is, how do you go about integration testing the output of a golang command line app?

Comment: @TheHippo My question isn't really about how to test the flags themselves.  The example I've given sort of boils down to that, but mostly because it's a trivial example.  Imagine a more complicated app where there are a number of other pieces of functionality that are tested in isolation.  I'd like to integration test the output of the app that uses these pieces together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bad example of parsing command line args, but it shows the framework I use to test command line args in my apps.

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    var city string
    parseFlags(&city, os.Args)

    log.Println(city)
}

func parseFlags(result *string, args []string) {
    cityDefault := "San Francisco"

    switch len(args) {
    case 3:
        *result = args[2]
    default:
        *result = cityDefault
    }
}
```

**main_unit_test.go**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "testing"
)

// TestParseFlags - test our command line flags
func TestParseFlags(t *testing.T) {
    var parseFlagsTests = []struct {
        flags    []string // input flags to the command line
        expected string   // expected
    }{
        {[]string{"/fake/loc/main"}, "San Francisco"},
        {[]string{"/fake/loc/main", "-c", "Los Angeles"}, "Los Angeles"},
        {[]string{"/fake/loc/main", "--city", "Los Angeles"}, "Los Angeles"},
    }

    for _, tt := range parseFlagsTests {
        var output string
        parseFlags(&output, tt.flags)
        if output != tt.expected {
            t.Errorf("expected: %s, actual: %s", tt.expected, output)
        }
    }
}
```

I typically use [this package](https://github.com/urfave/cli) to parse command line args in all of my apps. And I'll structure my code as follows (tests not shown, but they generally follow the gist of the test shown above):

**main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "myDir/cli"
)

func main() {
    // Grab the user inputed CLI flags
    cliFlags := cli.FlagsStruct{}
    cliErr := cli.StartCLI(&cliFlags, os.Args)
    if cliErr != nil {
        log.Println("Error grabbing command line args")
        log.Fatal(cliErr)
    }

    // Do stuff ...
}
```

**/myDir/cli.go**

```
package cli

import "github.com/urfave/cli"

// FlagsStruct - holds command line args
type FlagsStruct struct {
    MyFlag string
}

// StartCLI - gathers command line args
func StartCLI(cliFlags *FlagsStruct, args []string) error {
    app := cli.NewApp()
    app.Action = func(ctx *cli.Context) error {
        MyFlag := ctx.GlobalString("my-flag")

        // build the cli struct to send back to main
        cliFlags.MyFlag = MyFlag
        return nil
    }
    app.Authors = []cli.Author{
        {
            Email: "my@email.com",
            Name:  "Adam Hanna",
        },
    }
    app.Flags = []cli.Flag{
        cli.StringFlag{
            Name:  "my-flag, f",
            Usage: "My flag usage goes here",
            Value: "myDefault",
        },
    }
    app.Name = "myAppName"
    app.Usage = "My App's Usage"
    app.Version = "0.0.1"
    return app.Run(args)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about `test "$(./myapp -c "Los Angeles")" = "Los Angeles"`
and the same for -city. This has nothing to do with Go, just let your integration test suite  do the test.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense.  I guess I was hoping for a little more guidance from you about how you go about doing this.  But I guess that ends up getting a little too open ended for a Stack Overflow response, as it would devolve into an opinionated toolchain discussion (heaven forbid).  However, I think this points me in the right direction.  Thanks.